# Adding label to custom component as a child

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a custom component `TCard = class(TGraphicControl)`  I would like for when its created it would have a label inside it's area ex (top := 5 ) (left :=5)  and it would always put a `TLabel` on that `TCard` at that spot when created.

```
 type
   TCard = class(TGraphicControl)
   private
      FLPower:TLabel;
      procedure SetLPower(value:TLabel);
   protected
      procedure Paint; override;
   public
    property LPower: TLabel read FLpower write SetLPower;


...

 constructor Tcard.Create(AOwner: Tcomponent);
 begin
   inherited Create(AOwner);
   FLPower := TLabel.Create(self);
end

  procedure TCard.SetLPower(value: TLabel);
  begin
    FLPower.Assign(value);
  end;

  procedure Tcard.Paint;
  begin
      FLPower.Left := 5;
      FLPower.Top := 5;
  end;
```

I know what i have is not right, but i wanted to show something. Also if it helps, i plan in future to beable to do TCard.LPower.Caption := inttostr(somenumber); So if you can work that in then bonuse .. if not i can figure that out later..but wanted to give a heads up incase something you suggest would not work due to that. 
Thanks
glen

Comment: 'setLPower(value:Tlabel);`  i am more then sure its wrong i would think it would be `(value:string)`  or something so i could pass the data to the caption. but it gave me alot of errors. and did not want to head down wrong direction with the errors as the focus. Thus this question :D

Comment: What is your goal. Using a label created by the component or linking an external label. Since you are using a TGraphicControl (which can't be a parent for the label (which would be needed)) you might consider either using a TWincontol like TCustomPanel, creating your label (setting parent to your component) and adding a property for changing the caption of the label, or direcly draw the Caption on your TGraphicControl in `Paint`. Linking an external Label like shown in SetLPower (no need to create one) would be a complete different thing, which I would not recommend.

Comment: A TGraphicControl cannot be use as a container for a TLabel (or other controls). you need to draw the caption/text via `Paint`. Look at `TCustomLabel` source to see how it's done.

Comment: @bummi yes i would like for the component to create its own. as i would like each tcard (many of them) to hold there own label.  So i guess drawing the caption would be next best thing. can it draw text? and if show how ?

Comment: umm ok dont work.. ill keep working on it ..close this question as what it ask cant be done...maybe open aonther :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TGraphicControl cannot be used as a parent control and so you cannot adopt this approach.

A label is essentially something very simple. It's just text. You have chosen to use TGraphicControl so that implies that you are going to implement a Paint method.

So, instead of creating a label control, add a Text property of type string to your control. Then, in the Paint method, draw the text to the paint canvas. When the Text property is modified, invalidate your control so that it can be repainted.

In any case, doing it this way is the right way to do it. Adding extra controls just to draw text is over the top. You've picked the lightest weight control which is fine. Paint your card's background, and then paint any text that is required. Job done.

Comment: Thanks, wanted to note you must draw the text after any background is drawn